# Are developer-centric questions about the marketplace on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently closed a question on StackOverflow about services provided by Microsoft in relation to the app marketplace

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483681/large-wp-app-content-sizes-movie-multimedia

This is kind-of a grey area--its of more interest to programmers than users, definitely.  However questions about services provided by a company are definitely off-topic on StackOverflow.

Would this question be on-topic on wp.se?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Windows Phone programming questions appropriate for the site?](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-windows-phone-programming-questions-appropriate-for-the-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, any question related to development is not on topic here. This site is for questions regarding a problem you have on your phone. Development related, like in that post, is not in scope.

Questions on how the marketplace works are 100% welcome. However, IMO the question you linked to, (and this the one that would set the precedent here) would get closed almost immediately. It isn't just from the perspective of a developer, but a problem about developing on the phone. If the question was 'I am working on an app, and it is going to be very content heavy. What is the max size an app can be to be able to be downloaded over 3G' even though that is from a developers view, that would be OK.

What makes it OK is that the actual question is about the marketplace restrictions. not how to code around them

I am aware that this type of question is ok on android.se, but as of now it is not ok here. Where would we draw the line?

Answer (score -1):

I believe these kinds of questions *should be*.  These questions aren't "bad", in and of themselves.  Yes, they may change over time, but not frequently.  Or, not as frequently as any other platform-specific question.  Yes, they are about services offered by a company, but that company and those services are all up in WP7's business.

The precedent for this has already been set--it is acceptable to ask developer-centric app store questions on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-appstore) and [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market).

So IMHO the answer should be yes.

Comment: The precedent may have been set on those sites, but it hasn't been here. Questions on services Microsoft offers are ok, but as of now anything development related isnt

Comment: @Joe: Why should developer-centric questions be exiled from wp.se?  As long as they aren't in the "don't ask this here" category, they should be allowed.  The precedent has been set, I'd argue that there needs to be a good reason to reverse it.

Comment: The decision was made while it was in proposal at area51. the thought was, why should we start a new site for dev questions when SO is great for that?

Comment: @Joe: You don't quite understand the distinction.  Questions about developing WP7 apps are very on-topic on StackOverflow.  Questions about the marketplace, how it is operated, and how end users (developers qualify as well, you know) use it are *not* on topic.  So you can't say, "this question was asked from the perspective of a developer, therefore it is off topic here because StackOverflow."

Comment: I do understand and appreciate that "because its off topic on SO, therefore it is on topic here" is not a valid argument.  If I thought it was, I would have already migrated a few relevant questions over here.  Again, I would like to point out the precedent set by our fellow SE sites, [apple.se] and [android.se], and how they handle questions relating to development interaction with their platform's marketplace.  If there is a good reason why this precedent should be struck, I would like to hear it.  "Because StackOverflow" is not valid.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting word that my understanding of the precedent is incorrect.  Investigating.

Comment: Question on how the marketplace works are 100% welcome. However, IMO the question you linked to, (and this the one that would set the precedent here) would get closed almost immediately. It isn't just from the perspective of a developer (as you say), but a problem about developing on the phone. If the question was "I am working on an app, and it is going to be very content heavy. What is the max size an app can be to be able to be downloaded over 3G" even though that is from a developers view, that would be OK.

Comment: what makes it OK is that the actual question is about the marketplace restrictions. not how to code around them.

Comment: @Joe: I'm going to accept your answer.  I think my understanding of the precedent is incomplete/incorrect, and your above two comments make the distinction nicely.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you misunderstood (at least about Android).  We don't accept anything but end-user questions; all development, marketing, publishing, etc. questions are off-topic.  Thanks for following up on that though ;)